# Heroku Class is being cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku

I have a class called search that is a subclass of User. It seems when I deploy to Heroku that this class is cached in some way and it doesn't get reloaded. If I go to my production.rb file and change the config.cache_classes to false, it will load the correct cache and everythign will work fine. However, if I change that line back to true, it will use the old class from when I first deployed the file.

What do I have to do in my Rails code to have this work properly?

Comment: can you try heroku run console and then Rails.cache.clear . Not sure but its worth trying

Comment: I tried that. Doesn't seem like it did anything. I added in my application.rb that auto load path

config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/models/caregiver/**"]

Comment: what is the cache store that you have setup for your app? by default it is the file_store . if you have using anything different than the file_store then you may want to check on how to clear that specific cache store

Comment: It seems this has to do with eager loaded classes in Rails 4. Turning it off works but I think this is needed for some things.